# Android Room ORM: Support custom build of SQLite

Tags: android, android-room

I need to use a custom build of SQLite (based on sqlite.org version https://sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) so that I can use custom FTS Tokenizers and to use SEE to encrypt my databases.

I'm using the following code to create a Room database:

```
val mainDb = Room.databaseBuilder(context, MainDatabase::class.java, "main")
                .openHelperFactory(SqliteOrgSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
                .build()
```

I tried to implement my own "SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory" (SqliteOrgSQLiteOpenHelperFactory) and tried to implement all of the needed classes, but there are too many direct dependencies to "android.database.*"  and "android.database.sqlite.*".   All of these dependencies seem to need to be wrapped in "SupportXXX" classes

Example:
SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration depends on:

- android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler
- android.database.DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler
- android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory

SupportSQLiteDatabase depends on:

- android.database.sqlite.SQLiteTransactionListener
- android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory

Am I missing something?  Am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: I filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38430169) for more guidance here... though now I see that you filed [a similar issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38476154).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a github repo https://github.com/hannesa2/SafeRoom , based on attached zip from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38481640 which apply SQLCipher to Room