# How to install most recent version of Sqlite aar when using Room On Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

Im investigating Android Room databases in my current application.

I am trying to install the most recent version of Sqlite by employing the most recent `aar`

I have tried placing the `aar` in my database module `libs` folder and referencing that in my gradle file however the sqlite version displayed is always `3.22.0`
where the `aar` is `3.34.0`

what are the steps I need to follow to override the version of Sqlite supplied by default and use my downloaded aar file?

or

Is this not possible?

The sqlite.org website has this

> There are three ways to add the SQLite Android bindings to an
> application:
>
> By adding a pre-built aar file to the applications Android Studio
> project. By building an aar file, then adding it to the applications
> Android Studio project as in (1). By adding the SQLite Android
> bindings source code to and building it along with the other
> application code. By default, the SQLite Android bindings support
> Android API levels 16 and greater (Android versions 4.1 and up). There
> is also a separate version that supports Android API levels 9 and
> greater (Android version 2.3 and up). Please note the extra step
> involved in obtaining the code if you wish to use the version
> compatible with API level 9.
>
> 1. Using a Pre-Built aar File This is the most straightforward option. An "aar" file is similar to a jar file, except that it may contain
>    both compiled java classes and native code. An aar file for the latest
>    SQLite release usable with API levels 16 and up is available from this
>    page.
>
> There are two steps involved in adding an aar file to an Android
> Studio project:
>
> Import the module. In Android Studio 2.1 this is accomplished by
> selecting the "File" -> "New" -> "New Module..." menu and then
> choosing "Import JAR/AAR Package". Add a dependency on the new module
> to the main application module (or to all modules that will use the
> SQLite Android bindings). In Android Studio 2.1 the dependency may be
> created using the project structure dialog (select "File" -> "Project
> Structure...") or by adding code similar to the following to the
> application modules build.gradle file:
> dependencies {
> // Change "sqlite-android-3130000" to the name of the new module!
> compile project(':sqlite-android-3130000')
> }

I've tried this approach and room still reports the original version.
I believe there is an approach that will replace the bundled sqlite that is provided by Android as default

Comment: A similar question - [Android Room ORM: Support custom build of SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44097662/4858777)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To use a different database implementation with Room, you need to find (or create) a `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory` implementation and supply it to your `RoomDatabase.Builder` [via `openHelperFactory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#openHelperFactory(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory)):

```kotlin
val builder = Room.databaseBuilder(context, SomeDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
  .openHelperFactory(factory)
  .build()
```

The simplest way to do that is to use [Requery's standalone SQLite library](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android). You would use `RequerySQLiteOpenHelperFactory` as the implementation of the `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory`, and it will use Requery's packaged copy of SQLite instead of the framework one.

If, for some reason, you do not wish to use Requery's library, you would need to find an equivalent that you like, or you would need to implement the `SupportSQLite*` APIs yourself. I did that twice for SQLCipher for Android, and it is a pain, but it certainly is doable.

Comment: this does work, however using implementation 'io.requery:sqlite-android:3.33.0' seems to stop Android Studio database browser being able to access my devices DB

Answer (score 2):

SQLite comes bundled with the Android SDK, that means that SQLite version is changing with the increasing of the API level. Phone manufacturers can choose to ship different sqlite version with their device system.

Final verdict, you can't change it, unless running on rooted device.

Edit: [Guide](https://sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) suggests using different sqlite version to by-pass the built-in, that would require usage of different wrapper around the new sqlite which will not communicate with the system one. This prevents you from using android database packages, including Room.

Comment: I believe it is possible to override the package sqlite version on Android. as detailed here on the sqlite.org website... https://sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki. I have managed to achieve this in the past, however that was with basic Sqlite not with Room. I am certain it is possible to employ a different version of sqlite than that package with android

Comment: The guide you references says that you need to by pass the built-in sqlite, which means you shouldn't use the sdk API, but another wrapper, around SQLite. In any other case it explicitly says that you can't divorce the version.

Answer (score 0):

When investigating technology for data persistence in your android project, JPA for android should be considered. JPA is java standard, and JPA code can be re-used on java server side or other java client. see [Cmobilecom-JPA](https://cmobilecom.com/docs/jpa/latest/devguide/index.html) for android.