# How use custom libsqlite3.so with Android Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I found a issue when i was using Android Room on devices with android version 7 or older.

The issue is `printf` function in sqlite3 has three-digit separator capability but this feature is not available in older version of library.

I decided to attach sqlite3 library to my application so my application will use certain version of sqlite3.

I followed instructions in [SQLite Android Bindings](https://sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/install.wiki) and build aar file with my app. but i have to use `org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase` class to use sqlite library in AAR.

This is ok if write my own wrapper for sqlite access but when i am using Android Room is there any way to force Room to works with `org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase` instead of Android version.

Comment: [Builder.openHelperFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#openHelperFactory(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Factory)) ? I think this how you can use Room with SQLCipher for example

Comment: is there any implementation for that? or I have to implement it.

Comment: [How to install most recent version of Sqlite aar when using Room On Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65267351/1283554) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an implementation (Thanks to [bwt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283554/bwt))
[for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65267351/1283554)

gradle file

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'io.requery:sqlite-android:3.34.1'
    ...
}
```

application class

```
 database = Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyDB.class, "app.db")
            ...
            .openHelperFactory(new RequerySQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
            ...
            .build();
 dao = database.getDao();
```